# Multiple SubDomains Pointing to Different EE Posts

Tags: subdomain

What's the best way to get this to work?

I need to get a series of different subdomains to point to specific posts (URLs) from an EE site like this:

```
sub.domain-1.com --> domain.com/post1
sub.domain-2.com --> domain.com/post2
sub.domain-3.com --> domain.com/post3
```

Would this all be done at the domain host where the subdomain is being set up?

Answer (score 2):

This could be handled via `.htaccess` rules, as long as your sub-domain records point at your EE server. Here is an example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain-1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/post1 [L]
```

I'm not `.htaccess` expert so you may need to play around a little, but that'll do it. You should place these rules in your web roots .htaccess file, before anything else so they get caught early.

It's possible your domain host has some sort forwarding service for sub-domains, you'll have to ask them.

Comment: yes I think either way should work! if you control all hosts/servers/domains yourself it's probably viable to do this via domain-host. But this suggestion with htaccess rules has the advantage that you can all just manage from files, which you can keep as a template for future projects.

Comment: The 2 domains are on different servers and are managed by different hosts. What I need is the content from domain.com/post1 to be shown when sub.domain-1.com is visited. The htaccess posted - that would go in the root of the site on sub.domain-1.com, correct?